# How can I force Google Map to Lite Mode (no WebGL)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, canvas, google-maps-api-3

IE11 cannot handle the WebGL version of Google Maps.  For example, try dragging the map around on this page:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

If you visit maps.google.com, however, you will see it uses lite mode (canvas) and it works much smoother.  If visiting that page doesn't use canvas mode automatically, go to this URL:

www.google.com/maps/preview/?force=canvas

I'm developing against the Maps javascript API, so I need to know how to force this mode so my IE11 users aren't met with a terrible experience.

Answer (score 0):

Any issues you are seeing with the simple map example noted above are unrelated to webgl:  The JS API currently uses WebGL only for displaying Street View, and then only for certain OS/Browser combinations (and not currently ie11).

I was able to view the page in ie11 on a VM and it seemed ok.  Given it is not a webgl issue, can you be more clear what problem you are having in IE11?

Answer (score -3):

Use:

```
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions().liteMode(true);
```

You have more information at:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/lite